# How do I find the cell in a listobject table in a specific column that has "findstring" in it?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2013.
I have a listobject excel table called Assembly
I need to find the cell that contains "asmb1" in column "Item Name"

Here is what I have that does work:

```
Dim ItemRows As Integer
Set AssemblyTable = Worksheets("Assembly").ListObjects("Assembly")
ItemRows = AssemblyTable.ListColumns("Item Name").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
```

Here ItemRows gets the proper number of rows in the table.

Now I try to do the search and it fails:

```
Dim ItemRows As Integer
Set AssemblyTable = Worksheets("Assembly").ListObjects("Assembly")
ItemRows = AssemblyTable.ListColumns("Item Name").DataBodyRange.Find("asmb1")
```

This fails with the following message:

```
Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set
```

Thanks for any ideas.
Rich

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the error(s) you are receiving. Theoretically, the code should work, so it's tempting to think there's a naming error (Error 9: Subscript out of range).

Comment: Likely culprits are the unqualified `Worksheet` property or case sensitive items.

Comment: What error did you get with the code you posted?  "some sort of error" is not a useful description of what happens when you run your code.

Answer (score 1):

`ItemRows` has to be defined like a `Range`, after you set `ItemRows` to get the result of Find, like that:

```
Dim ItemRows as Range
Set ItemRows = AssemblyTable.ListColumns("Item Name").DataBodyRange.Find("asmb1")
```